# Using AWS federated identity from Github Action to assume role in another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, amazon-iam

I have 2 AWS accounts, source and destination. AWS OIDC federation is configured so that I can use the token from Github Action to login to AWS using the official action:

```
 - name: configure aws credentials
   uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
   with:
     role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::<source account id>:role/role-A
     aws-region: us-east-1
```

Now, I want to use Terraform to manage resources on both accounts, source and destination. I followed a [guide](https://medium.com/scalereal/how-to-use-multiple-aws-providers-in-a-terraform-project-672da074c3eb) to allow `role-A` to assume `role-B` in the destination account.

I am getting a weird error:

```
Error: 022-08-31T09:28:04.246] [ERROR] default - 
Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: IAM Role (arn:aws:iam::<destination account id>:role/role-B) cannot be assumed.

There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
  * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
  * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
  * The role ARN is not valid

Error: operation error STS: AssumeRole, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 7227d0e8-e955-45ac-8f08-fc48699564e3, api error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::<source account id>:assumed-role/role-A/GitHubActions is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<destination account id>:role/role-B


  with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"].security,
  on cdk.tf.json line 4125, in provider.aws[1]:
4125:       }
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Role A has the following IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<destination account id>:role/role-B"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'll appreciate help figuring out why the request is failing... It seems like everything is configured correctly...

Edit:

Added the trust policy for Role B:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<source account id>:role/role-A"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check who can assume the role B and what are the conditions required to assume it (Trust Relationship ), I had an issue like this and found that the role B doesn't allow roles to assume it without MFA enabled

Comment: Added the trust policy, it looks like it should allow it...

Comment: did you already went through this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/14738 ? i

Comment: I am not sure how it is related - this is not what I am trying to do